# 1 test case (which I dont know) is failing, can someone check my code and tell me whats wrong?

Tags: java

During his study in Amazing International University-Bangladesh Kazi Hossain accidentally made a space ship doing a course assignment. He named the space ship Eagle. Now he wants to travel other habitable planets in the galaxy with Eagle. As Kazi is a very brave guy he wants to start his space journey travelling the farthest planet in the galaxy first.

The co-ordinate of the planet Kazi is currently in (planet Earth) is always (0,0). You are given the co-ordinates of the other N habitable planets in the galaxy in a 2D Cartesian plane. You have to find the index of the farthest planet considering the Euclidean distance from planet Earth (0,0). Indices starts from 1 to N.

Input Format

Each of the test cases starts with an integer N (1≤N≤50), denoting the number of planets. Each of the next N lines contains two integers xi yi (-10000≤xi,yi≤10000) describing the co-ordinates of the planets in the galaxy.

Constraints

xi yi (-10000≤xi,yi≤10000)

Output Format

For each case print the index of the farthest planet from Earth that Kazi will be travelling first. If there’s multiple possible answers output the one that comes first in the input. See sample input output for clarification.

Sample Input 0

3
4 0
0 5
2 2
Sample Output 0

2

My Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt(), ar[]=new int[2*n], c=0;
        double num;
        for(int i=0;i<2*n;++i)  
            ar[i]=sc.nextInt();
            
        double max=Math.sqrt(ar[0]*ar[0]+ar[1]*ar[1]);
        for(int i=0;i<=2*n-2;i=i+2){
            num=Math.sqrt(ar[i]*ar[i]+ar[i+1]*ar[i+1]);
            if(num>max){   
                max=num;
                c=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c);
     }
```

Comment: The main Problem is the output. I think you needed to print (c/2) + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if the *very 1st planet* is the farthest one? Then once computed

```
  double max=Math.sqrt(ar[0]*ar[0]+ar[1]*ar[1]);
```

*will not be changed* and so do `c`; in this case the answer will be `c=0` which is *incorrect* (`c == 1` is expected). In general case, another possible issue is `Math.sqrt` (potential source of rounding errors) which is *redundant* here.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = sc.nextInt();
     
    int max = -1;
    int index = -1;

    // i == 0 is the Earth, 1..n - other planets; so we start from 1 
    // No need in array: we can just read value after value 
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      // Let's keep it simple: we just read x and then y (no ar[i + 1])
      int x = sc.nextInt();
      int y = sc.nextInt();

      // No need in square root: we can just compare squared distances 
      int distance = x * x + y * y;

      if (distance > max) {
        index = i;
        max = distance;
      }       
    }       

    System.out.println(index);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! as you had said the problem came when the first planet was the farthest one, i should have payed more attention thank you very much!